# JSONObject, JSONArray Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

como podria obtener un JSONObject segun su posicion, supongamos... tengo este JSON:

```
"response":[{
    "comidas":[
        {
            "sabor":"desconocido",
            "cantidad","50",
            "precio","32",
            "cocina","N/A",
        },
        {
            "sabor":"desconocido",
            "cantidad","10",
            "precio","20",
            "cocina","N/A",
        },
        {
            "sabor":"desconocido",
            "cantidad","20",
            "precio","105",
            "cocina","N/A",
        },
        {
            "sabor":"desconocido",
            "cantidad","40",
            "precio","10001",
            "cocina","N/A",
        },
        {
            "sabor":"desconocido",
            "cantidad","80",
            "precio","10",
            "cocina","N/A",
        },
    ]
}]
```

entonces quiero acceder a estas comidas por por posicion, ejemplo posicion 0 serian los JSONObjects sabor desconocido, cantidad 50, precio 32 y cocina N/A, etc... si quiero la posicion 3 seria sabor desconocido cantidad 40... etc...

este es mi codigo, obvio no lo tengo asi pero quisiera acomodarlo para que funcionara de esa forma como les explico:

```
 try {

                for(int c = 0;c<=jsonArr.length()-1;c++){
                    JSONObject itemObj = (JSONObject) jsonArr.get(c);
                    TableRow tbr = new TableRow(ctx);

                    for(int z =1; z<=itemObj.length();z++){
                        String temp = itemObj.getString("0");
                        TextView tvtemp = new TextView(ctx);
                        tvtemp.setText(temp);
                        tvtemp.setPadding(40,20,40,20);
                        tbr.addView(tvtemp);
                    }

                    if(s==0) {
                        tbr.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, R.color.backgroundGray));
                        s=1;
                    }else{
                        s=0;
                    }
                    tbl.addView(tbr);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

se que con .get(0) .get(3) puedo tener estas posiciones pero a la vez, quiero acceder a la posicion del JSONObject de cada array.

ejemplo..

JSONObject item = array.get(0);

entonces quiero que item me tome la posicion 2

osea precio y me retorne 32, espero explicarme bien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo he resuelto, me fije que del jsonobject podria obtener su key, y aplique el codigo de esta forma:

```
    try {

        for(int c = 0;c<=jsonArr.length()-1;c++){
            JSONObject itemObj = (JSONObject) jsonArr.get(c);
            TableRow tbr = new TableRow(ctx);

            Iterator<String> keys = itemObj.keys();


            for(int z =0; z<=itemObj.length()-1;z++){
                String actual = keys.next();
                String temp = itemObj.getString(actual);
                TextView tvtemp = new TextView(ctx);
                tvtemp.setText(temp);
                tvtemp.setPadding(40, 20, 40, 20);
                 tbr.addView(tvtemp);
            }

            if(s==0) {
                tbr.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, R.color.backgroundGray));
                s=1;
            }else{
                s=0;
            }
            tbl.addView(tbr);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo el array que indicas y que: JSONObject miObjeto es ese que indicas seria asi

```
try{
 JSONObject miObjeto; //El que indicas;
 JSONArray arrayResponse = miObjeto.getJSONArray("response"); //primer array 
 JSONObject comidasObject = arrayResponse.getJSONObject(0); // primer jsonobject del array


 JSONArray comidasArray = comidasObject.getJSONArray("comidas"); //arreglo de comidas
/*este ya es el que contiene el arreglo de lo que necesitas y lo accedes por index 0,1,2 
ejemplo:*/
 JSONObject primerItem = comidasArray.getJSONObject(0);
/*
 {
  "sabor":"desconocido",
  "cantidad","50",
  "precio","32",
  "cocina","N/A",
 }

*/


}catch(Exception e){/*captura la exception aqui*/}
```

Comment: lo siento pero no es lo que buscaba ya que  igual debo mencionar la etiqueta y es precisamente lo que quiero evitar para que sea totalmente automatico segun el numero de items que tenga el JSON

Comment: genial, me alegro que encontraras solucion amigo :)

Comment: muchas gracias.